# Detach a tab in a fullscreen window in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to detach a tab in a fullscreen Chrome window? I find no way. When I need to do this, I have to un-maximize the window, drag to detach the tab, and then restore the window in fullscreen again. This is burdensome.

Comment: When you detach it you want to put it in the back or to make it front alone ?

Comment: I hope it is moved to a new virtual desktop or to an existing non-fullscreen virtual desktop.

Comment: Hold cmd, type LCWNV and press enter? ;) (focuses on the location bar, copies the address, closes the tab, opens a new fullscreen window, pastes the address)

Comment: @onik, this seems legitimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd been idly wondering about this for a month or two as well. The answer is no, but there is an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-detachreattach-t/fcdnbffbdamioochllldblfcblgifjcp) that can enable a keyboard shortcut that does the same thing. Here's a [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/en/detach$20a$20tab$20in$20fullscreen/chrome/y-9Xfy8w8Ws/dji_YGe98EoJ) to the Google Product Forums topic that helped me, too. I haven't tested this extension myself, but the user who posted on Google Forums did.

Comment: I tried the extension and it works. Thank you. It use Ctrl-Shift-;, but Cmd-Shift-; also works.

Answer (score 3):

We have a Fix for this!

In Chrome Version 52 beta we can now enable a new Flag to detach a Tab in a Fullscreen Window on Mac. Without Workarounds or extensions!

The Flag:
chrome://flags/#enable-fullscreen-in-tab-detaching

And here the Bug-Report with Status Fixed:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=507942

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! We're looking for complete answers – could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them. But this is a valid bug fix. Looks like Chrome 52 has solved this!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the extension suggested by Matthew had stopped working for a while, so I'll put in my own solution. I personally use the [Mac Fullscreen Tab Mover](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mac-fullscreen-tab-mover/kcckoecdhkegbkoboplfcakhinocgibp) and binded the commands with option+left/right (so convenient!), but I also found others like [Tab Mover](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-shifter-and-window-mo/hmmkcfoallifpmilkijjikcbcnnbcbih) which seem to do the same thing.

Comment: Cheers dude.. This works great. I've made Shift+Option+X to detach as new window. And configured Shift+option+Up to maximize a window in next monitor using BTT (BetterTOuchTool). Saves huge time :D

Answer (score 0):

With the latest Chrome Version (Version70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit) ) you can drag a tab from full screen mode Chrome. click-hold and drag it horizontally along the top until you reach the next screen. Releasing it at this point will give you the tab on your second screen in non full screen mode. If you click-hold and drag it downwards, it opens the selected tab in a new full screen window on the original screen.

Comment: It always tears off to new full screen for me and it is incredibly annoying. The only workaround I've found so far is to drop it in an existing chrome window on another screen to prevent it from maximizing, and then tear it off again.